# PHPUnit 3.5.13 manual installation?

Tags: php, installation, phpunit

is there any way to install phpunit 3.5.13 manually.... (existing solutions are not working)

Comment: "not working" is not a good problem description. what error messages/problems are you having?

Comment: Manually like how? And on where?

Comment: Sorry, its not showing anything... blank screen (no errors)

Comment: meanwhile i'am working on 3.4 successfully

Answer (score 3):

If you are unable to perform [the recommended installation steps](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.5/en/phpunit-book.html#installation), then you should be able to [simply grab the source](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/) and work with it directly -- scroll down to the section titled "Using PHPUnit From a Git Checkout"